# how can I remove the subnavigation overlap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, hover, submenu

I am trying to create a sub navigation. Right now I have two subnav. When i hover over the first item on the main menu the corresponding submenu appears. But when I hover over the second item the second sub nav appears OVER the first one. How can I write the code so that this does not happen?

url: http://arabic001.com

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#arbNavText01').mouseover(function()  {
            $('#subNav01').show('slow');
        });

        $('#subNav01').mouseleave(function() {
            $('#subNav01').hide('slow');
        }); 


         $('#arbNavText02').mouseover(function()  {
            $('#subNav02').show('slow');
        });

        $('#subNav02').mouseleave(function() {
            $('#subNav02').hide('slow');
        }); 



        })
```

I just tried the below suggestion from Scott and I am not able to show and hide the submenu on hover. Any ideas of how to solve this problem? Here are my new codes:

html

```
<div id="menu01" class="menu_item">
            <div id="engNavText01">Alphabet</div>
            <div id="arbNavText01">الأحرف</div>
            <div id="subNav01" style="display:none;">
                <a href="colors" class="subNav">
                    <span style="font-size:26px; cursor:pointer;">قراءة</span</a>
                    <br>reading<br><br>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="menu02" class="menu_item">
            <div id="engNavText02">Numbers</div>
            <div id="arbNavText02">الأحرف</div>
            <div id="subNav02" style="display: none; ">
                <a href="colors" class="subNav">
                    <span style="font-size:26px; cursor:pointer;">قراءة</span</a>
                    <br>reading<br><br>
        </div>
        </div>
```

and the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.menu_item').children().hover(
function(){
    $subNav = $(this).parents('menu_item').children("div[id^='subNav'");
    if ($subNav.css('display', 'none')){
        $subNav.show('slow');
    }
},
function(){
    $(this).parents('menu_item').children("div[id^='subNav'").hide('slow');
});

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a mouseleave event, but you've only attached it to the submenu.  So in order to make a menu disappear, the user will have to hover over the submenu and then move out.  You could achieve what you want by hiding other submenus before opening a new one.  So keeping your mouseleave events as you have them, you could modify your 2 mouseover events to this:

```
    $('#arbNavText01').mouseover(function()  {
        $('#subNav02').hide('slow');
        $('#subNav01').show('slow');
    });
    $('#arbNavText02').mouseover(function()  {
        $('#subNav01').hide('slow');
        $('#subNav02').show('slow');
    });
```

Edit for comment:
I was thinking about that when I went and looked at your page originally.  I think if you used a slightly different structure in your html this could be done.  Right now your menu divs aren't clearly structurally related to each other so maybe add a div that can contain the 3 elements associated with each menu item.

I'm going to spit ball an idea, it may not even work let alone be the best way.

```
<div id="menu01" class="menu_item">
    <div id="engNavText01">Alphabet</div>
    <div id="arbNavText01">الأحرف</div>
    <div id="subNav01" style="display: none; ">
        <a href="colors" class="subNav"><span style="font-size:26px; cursor:pointer;">قراءة</span</a>
        <br>reading<br><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="menu02" class="menu_item">...
```

Edited JS, I think now it could work

```
$('.menu_item').hover(
    function(){
        $subNav = $(this).children("div[id^='subNav']");
        if ($subNav.css('display', 'none')){
            $subNav.show('slow');
        }
    },
    function(){
        $(this).children("div[id^='subNav']").hide('slow');
    }
);
```

Was trying it out with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vppKJ/3/), seems alright there.  Might need some modification for your uses.

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly, except that now I have to do the same thing for the rest of the subnav. I have eight of them and I don't want to repeat myself in the code. Is there an elegant way of writing it so that there is a class, for example. Where I can ask it to show only one submenu at a time?

Comment: I was looking for away to put them in divs the way you suggested in my html file. Thanks for that improvement in my codes. But the js codes did not work.